# Remove standalone attribute from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have an xml file which I need to modify and write it back to an outputfile.
The problem is that the result outputfile contains an extra attribute 'standalone' in the root declartion which does not exist in the original inputfile.
Is there any way how I can prevent from XmlDocument adding this attribute ?

The code I have tried:

```
//read input xml
 XmlDocument xDoc  = new XmlDocument();
 xDoc.Load(originalFile);

//do some stuff
//....

//write back to output
using(XmlTextWriter xml2 = new XmlTextWriter(outputFile, Encoding.UTF8) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
            {   
                xDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, "");
                xDoc.Save(xml2);

            }
```

inputfile contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
...
```

output.xml contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *standalone* parameter should be `null` or `String.empty`.

```
xDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
```

Also `CreateXmlDecleration` just creates a declaration object. You still need to add it to the document, like this:

```
XmlDeclaration xDecl = xDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
if (xDoc.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
  xDoc.ReplaceChild(xDecl, xDoc.FirstChild);
else
  xDoc.InsertBefore(xDecl, xDoc.DocumentElement);
```

Comment: null or string.empty still does not work. I even think that the whole "xDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, "");" line does not make any difference

Comment: Updated my answer - just realised you also need to add the declaration object to your document for it to work.

Comment: Now I get an InvalidOperationException 'Cannot insert the node in the specified location.'

Comment: I can't reproduce that error, but it might be because the document already has an xml declaration. Have updated my code to support documents both with and without the xml declaration.